# Monodroid: Exception in XmlDocument.SelectNodes() method

Tags: exception, xmldocument, xamarin.android, selectnodes

I am struggling with some Monodroid code that should be simple, but is causing an unexpected exception. The code throws an exception when I try to invoke SelectNodes() on an XmlDocument object.

This is the code:

XmlDocument handXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

XmlDeclaration dec = handXmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);

handXmlDocument.AppendChild(dec);

XmlElement root = handXmlDocument.CreateElement("friendslist");

handXmlDocument.AppendChild(root);

XmlElement friendElement = handXmlDocument.CreateElement("friend");

friendElement.SetAttribute("locationx", "35");

friendElement.SetAttribute("locationy", "46");

friendElement.SetAttribute("phone", "4085556803");

root.AppendChild(friendElement);

XmlNodeList friendNodeList = handXmlDocument.SelectNodes("/friendslist/friend");

and here is the exception:

E/mono    (  365): [0x45eec0:] EXCEPTION handling: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Console
E/FriendsView(  365): Exception parsing XML document: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Console
E/FriendsView(  365): Inner exception parsing XML document: System.ExecutionEngineException: SIGILL
E/FriendsView(  365):   at System.Console..cctor () [0x00019] in /Users/plasma/Work/mono-android-trunk/mcs/class/corlib/System/Console.cs:127

I have no idea why System.Console is involved here! Thanks for any help, Martin

Comment: Product is in beta, please report bugs to on the mailing list or Monodroid bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding this in the hopes it might help anyone else who hits the same problem. It turns out that this was a bug in Monodroid 1.0.8980 which was fixed by the time of Monodroid 1.0.9186. Upgrading to the new release fixed my problem.